# How can I format this table with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dcast

I am starting with this table

| Gene | SampleID | Timepoint | log2_CPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| krt19 | 7578 | 14 | 123 |
| sftpd1 | 7578 | 14 | 32 |
| Cxcl13 | 7578 | 14 | 365 |
| krt19 | 7458 | 14 | 125 |
| sftpd1 | 7458 | 14 | 36 |
| Cxcl13 | 7458 | 14 | 330 |

and I need to convert to something like this

| SampleID | Timepoint | krt18 | sftpd1 | Cxcl13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7578 | 14 | 123 | 32 | 365 |
| 7458 | 14 | 125 | 36 | 330 |

Can someone please help me generate an R code for this? Thanks

I tried doing it manually & by using R codes. None worked. It is a very large dataset, and I would appreciate the help.

```
formattedDATA <-dcast(setDT(rawDATA), formula = c("Timepoint","SampleID") ~ Gene)

ERROR
> formattedDATA <-dcast(setDT(rawDATA), formula = c("Timepoint","SampleID") ~ Gene)
Using 'log2_CPM' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
Error in vapply(X = x, FUN = fun, ..., FUN.VALUE = NA_character_, USE.NAMES = use.names) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

Comment: This would be a good resource I would use pivot_wider : https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html , your id cols are most likely SampleID and Timepoint, with names from Gene and the values from log2_CPM

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your code by using `dput()`.  Reduce your datset to the first six rows, then `dput(formattedDATA[1:6,]])`. Its output can be posted into your question as a reproducible example.

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Gene, values_from = log2_CPM)`

Answer (score 0):

Answer

`formattedDATA <-dcast(setDT(rawDATA), formula = SampleID + Timepoint  ~ Gene , value.var = "log2_CPM")`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**